# How to execute two grep commands on the same file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file. I want to select the lines that does not start with `www.` and does not contains slashes. I want to output the result into `result.txt`

To achieve the first requirement:

`grep -v '^www\.' myfile.txt > result.txt`.

To achieve the second, I will take result.txt and execute:

```
grep -v '/' result.txt > result2.txt
```

Is there any better shorcut to execute several commands on the file and store the result into one output file: `result.txt`

I am aware of `|` to execute several commands where the output of the command on the left of `|` is input of the command in the right of `|`. What I do not know is, in case of grep or any other command, should I use the file name in the command on the right of `|`. In other words, should it be:

```
grep -v '^www\.' myfile.txt | grep -v '/' > result.txt
```

OR

```
grep -v '^www\.' myfile.txt | grep -v '/' mfile.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -v -e '^www\.' -e '/' myfile.txt > result.txt`

Answer (score 2):

No fear to use pipes. Alexander answer is the best and purrest, but in case I look for the best formula first, I use some step:

1. `head file |grep 'first-condition' |grep 'next-conditon'` :: gives you
   overwiev
2. `cat file |grep 'first-condition' |grep 'next-conditon' |wc -l` ::
   gives amount
3. `grep --color 'complex-condition'` :: highlights the real selection

In final step you can create a very complex regexp e.g.:

```
egrep -v '(^www\.)|(/)' myfile.txt > result.txt
```

Sometimes it is necessary to use other string analysing commands `awk`, `sed`, `cut` etc. Using the pipe is then very usefull.